# angular 1.5 - one way data flow - parent updates child primitive value the first time only, one-time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I'm new to angular 1.5 and learning the best practice of one way data flow.  I'm going off of this jsfiddle, and am really confused about one piece of behavior in particular.

I understand that data flows down from parent to child and is one way bound, ie, changes in the child do not affect the parent.  It seems like this works for the object in question all the time, but for the primitive, the one way data flow happens initially, but the the primitive value stays the same (10) as defined in the isolate components update values function.  So if you do the following:

1. click "Change Parent Values", the child receives the data and is
   updated.
2. click "Change Isolate Values" the isolate/child primitive
   value changes to ten and the parent is unaffected
3. observe that after updating the parents values via "Change Parent
   Values" again, the isolate primitive value **is 10
   forever**, even though the object updates correctly. Why is that, and how can the child receive updated
   primitive values from the parent while following angular 1.5 one way
   data flow best practices?

https://jsfiddle.net/toddmotto/wauana12/

```
this.updateValues = function () {
  this.prim = 10;
  this.obj = {
    john: {
      age: 35,
      location: 'Unknown'
    }
  };
};
```

---

Update:
so inside this.updateValues in the parent controller 
I changed `this.somePrimitive = 33` to

```
this.somePrimitive = Math.random();
```

and it worked the way I expected, I am still unsure as to why and would appreciate help in understanding...

---

Update 2: I think it is because the parent controller updateValues function is not actually making a change to the primitive, so there's no way for the child to be aware of the update.  The update above forces a change to the primitive.  Since the object is by reference it will always be "changed".

However, I feel like the intent of one way data binding is lost here and broken (React ftw). Is there anyway to manually update the child, not relying on the parent $watch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because the parent controller updateValues function is not actually making a change to the primitive, so there's no way for the child to be aware of the update. The update above (with Math.random()) forces a change to the primitive. Since the object is by reference it will always be "changed", but since primitives are immutable it won't be. Probably not the best idea to pass primitives that are supposed to be reassigned to child components, and play nicely with angulars change detection by using objects.